# Facebook, send sk and app_data in send Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app that has a function to send app_data as part of the URL.

When the link is clicked the dialog pops up to select friends and the link at this stage is correct.

However when friend receives the message the link is to the business page no the original link.

When you first open the dialog you get a link like:
e.g http://www.facebook.com/pages/Autofficina/136519656411435?sk=app_175456335854933&app_data=carID%3D110&ref=nf

but the friend receives:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Autofficina/136519656411435

Is there anyway to link to the app?

My Code:

```
function send(carId, vname, image) {
var theUrl = dealersPageURL + '?sk=app_' + appID + '&app_data=' + encodeURIComponent('carID=' + carId);
vname += ' on ' + branchName;
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: vname,
    link: theUrl,
    picture: image,
    redirect_uri: null,
    display: 'popup'
});
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  You should log it with Facebook. Post the bug # here for reference.  Thanks.